# Solidity: private vs public variables

Tags: solidity, contract-design, myetherwallet

In a smart contract, if we make a member variable `public`:

**Question** 1: Can a malicious party write a transaction/contract and change the value/state of the `public` variable in the contract?

**Question** 2: Would the problem be solved by only turning public to `private`?

For instance, if in a contract we have:

```
address private owner;
```

and in the contract constructor we have:

```
 owner = msg.sender;
```

then we have a getter function like:

```
get_owner() returns (address){
  return owner;
```

}

then nobody can change owner, but if have

```
address public owner;
```

someone may change it later on?

---

But if we have a getter function as above, [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) (to interact with a contract on testrpc) does not read/return owner, unless we turn public owner to a private one.

**Question** 3: Why MyEtherWallet does not return a value, for the getter functions that we write?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. **No**. For public variables with a global scope within a contract, only getters for those variables are automatically created by the compiler, not setters.
2. Because of the first answer, this does not apply.
3. About MyEtherWallet I can't understand the issue, but it should be able to automatically show all public functions of the contract (getters included), like other tools do (i.e. remix). Please note that usually a ÐApp expose functions reading the ABI of the contract. The ABI in any case is always provided by the user (for some famous contract MEW can suggest to the user a known ABI)

You can find more useful information about variables and functions visibility in the [official documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?#visibility-and-getters).