# How to get access to the storage mapping through the solidity assembler?

Tags: solidity, assembly, solidity-0.5.x

referencing the question [How to get access to the storage array through the solidity assembler?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69931/how-to-get-access-to-the-storage-array-through-the-solidity-assembler?newreg=1603cff12add440f8d32362065aaef66) I have been trying to figure out how to access the mapping (or variable y from the question).  The documentation has an example, but of course it has to be overly complicated and access a 2d mapping.  However it does say that to get the value of a key (k) of a mapping you hash k . p and load this slot.  Does this mean to get the mapping from the similarly asked question you would do:

```
contract Foo {
  uint internal x; // Storage slot #0
  mapping (uint => address) internal y; // Storage slot #1
  uint [] internal z; // Storage slot #2

  function zElement (uint key) public view returns (uint r) {
    assembly {
      sload(keccak256(add(key, y_slot), 32))
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:  fixed the link to go to the correctly mentioned question.
EDIT2: should compile now i think.

Comment: Would be useful if you posted a code which compiles successfully.

Comment: the code was taken from the previously asked question.  I guess to get it to work u just move the closing bracket of the contract to after the function.  I merely had a question related to that answer so I took the answer and edited the sload line for my question.

Comment: So what part are you missing then? Just the `uint => address` instead of `uint => uint` part?

Comment: I guess?  i changed it for address but technically nothing was missing.  trying to access a mapping value in assembly and I can't figure it out.

Comment: it just doesn't make much sense to me, especially for a key of uint(0) since that would evaluate to sload(keccak256(y_slot, 32)) and the docs say keccak256(y_slot, 32) should be unused for mappings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution**

```
function getStorageValue(uint num, uint slot) public view returns (address result) {
    assembly {
        // Store num in memory scratch space (note: lookup "free memory pointer" if you need to allocate space)
        mstore(0, num)
        // Store slot number in scratch space after num
        mstore(32, slot)
        // Create hash from previously stored num and slot
        let hash := keccak256(0, 64)
        // Load mapping value using the just calculated hash
        result := sload(hash)
    } 
}
```

---

**Explanation**

To obtain the address stored behind a uint to address mapping, you have to obtain the storage key and subsequently load the data stored in that position by using `sload`. To do so you have to hash 64 bytes using `keccak256`. Those 64 bytes are composed of 32 bytes of the uint you want to use as a key concatenated to 32 bytes of the storage slot. The low-level `keccak256` call takes a memory address and a number of bytes as arguments, therefore those values have to be stored cohesive in memory before by using `mstore`. The storage slot is determined by the position in which the storage variable is declared in comparison to other storage variables, starting from 0.

Comment: omg ur my hero!  I've read the opcode info so many times and yet i somehow missed or just didn't care about the fact that keccak256 uses memory location as its first input and not the uint(or bytes32) value.  man i feel special.

Comment: @Bobdabear I sure know that feeling! Glad I could help :)

Comment: @sea212 Hi there, I am wondering if you could also help with initializing a mapping with assembly.

Comment: @Maxareo Hello, please post a new question about your issue. I cannot promise to help right now, but the community in general is able to and might resolve your issue.