# How does Ethereum fit a mapping into storage?

Tags: storage, mapping

Probably a silly question, but how does Ethereum fit a mapping into storage? I am used to simple types like arrays, so I don't understand how "Solidity's mapping uses the entire 256-bit addressable memory space." I am guessing its something simple like only non-zero values take up space, but I would like to know what code/algorithm/concept was used to achieve this. Thanks!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get access to the storage mapping through the solidity assembler?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80529/how-to-get-access-to-the-storage-mapping-through-the-solidity-assembler)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you declare a mapping like in the following contract :

```
contract MappingExample {
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
}
```

The variable balances is assigned to storage slot 0 (simply because it is the first one). **But the mapped elements are elsewhere.**

To compute the storage slot or location of the mapped elements, the following is used :

```
slot = keccak256([key, mappingSlot]) // concatenate key and mapping slot
```

The thing is that non allocated storage slots default to the value 0. So every key that was not assigned a value points to a non allocated storage slot for which the EVM can return the value 0 directly. There is no need to actually store 2^256 - 1 slots just because a mapping was declared.

If you are curious about that you can see the implementation of the SLOAD OPCODE in go-ethereum [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go#L508) that calls the evm.StateDB.GetState method defined [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/0a7672fc9aa816ff0ae385da28f2cbd5b36e3677/core/state/statedb.go#L308):

```
func (s *StateDB) GetState(addr common.Address, hash common.Hash) common.Hash {
    stateObject := s.getStateObject(addr)
    if stateObject != nil {
        return stateObject.GetState(s.db, hash)
    }
    return common.Hash{}
}
```

As you can see, `if stateObject == nil` then `common.Hash{}` is returned. This is a zeroed 32 bytes array. Basically, a zeroed out storage field that doesn't need to be stored in case the address has not state associated to it.

In turn (not directly) it will call GetCommittedState defied [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/0a7672fc9aa816ff0ae385da28f2cbd5b36e3677/core/state/state_object.go#L187). This method is pretty big so I'm not pasting it here, the same logic follows if the key cannot be recovered from the state trie a default value of 0 will be returned.

So, refining our example a little:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract MappingExample {

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    constructor() {
        // Setting balance of an arbitrary address.
        balances[address(0x10)] = 100;
    }

}
```

You can read balances[address(0x10)] with the following Web3 code:

import Web3 from "web3";

```
const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545");

// ADDRESS OF OUR CONTRACT (CHANGE IT FOR YOUR OWN)
const contractAddress = "0xd4EC28074b7A66F536D9feCf9b2f81B962215e69";

// STORAGE SLOT OF THE MAPPING
const mappingSlot = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';

// KEY THAT WE WANT TO READ IN THE MAPPING
const key =         '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010';

// COMPUTE THE ACTUAL STORAGE SLOT OF THE VALUE ASSOCIATED WITH THE KEY
const balanceSlot = web3.utils.soliditySha3({t: 'bytes', v: key + mappingSlot});

const balance = await web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, balanceSlot);
console.log(web3.utils.toNumber(balance));
// DISPLAYS : 100
```

Because the hash (interpreted as a storage index) is stored in the EVM, any unknown value will return a 256 bit 0 value as shown in the `GetState` function, this 0 value doesn't need to be stored.

In essence, every value in a mapping is mapped to something. But not all values are stored in the contract storage space, only the values that have been set. Making it a quite efficient structure that doesn't require every node to allocate 2^256 - 1 bits for each mapping in existence.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Just edited my answer, getState returns 0 if the address has no storage associated to it, I added a link to getCommittedState where the logic happens: if the address has a storage associated but the key is not set then again, a default value of 0 is returned.