# Do contract storage locations that map wallet address to balance change

Tags: storage, balances, storage-pointer

***Will the storage location of a wallet address' balance change over time?
If so, is it a problem largely associated with edge cases/unimportant tokens or is it a pervasive risk?***

**For some background:** I'm trying to determine the net balance impact (ETH and ERC tokens) of a transaction. To verify a wallet address' balance change for an ERC-20 token, I'm determining the storage location of their balance for that token's contract. I'm hoping that the wallet's storage location won't change so that I don't have to continually re-verify an address' balance storage location.

**Some areas I've briefly looked into that I think may have an impact:**

- storage collisions (but I would think this is isolated to unimportant tokens since there are standards to avoid this)
- proxy patterns (I'm unsure if there are proxy strategies that result in changed storage locations)

Comment: What do you mean by *storage location of a wallet address' balance*? Perhaps, did you mean the storage slot where a mapping entry is stored? Storage slots have to be modified explicitly, they won't change "magically".

Comment: Yes, a storage slot for the balances mapping (ex: `mapping(address => uint256) private _balances`). I understand they won't change magically but do you know if there are instances where a person won't map to their prior storage slot? If they have a balance, then go to a zero balance, then have a balance once more would they still map to the same storage slot?

Comment: Within the same contract it won´t change, `_balances[addr]` will map to the same slot always. The slot used by a mapping entry uses a formula https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114186/how-does-ethereum-fit-a-mapping-into-storage. In any case you shouldn´t depend on the slot number for most cases, it is a low level detail.