# How to values in mapping type struct with solidity assembly?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, assembly

I have a special needs, store the mapping type struct with assembly code. thank you very for everyone who can response this question.

**Need your help how to write something in assembly**

Here is how I am trying todo

```
 mapping(uint256 => MyStruct) public myStruct;
                  
       struct MyStruct {
        uint256 value;
        address myAddress;
        string email;
      }
            
      function addUser(key, value, myaddress, email) public {
      
       MyStruct storage mystructInfo = myStruct[key]
      
      assembly {
        sstore(add(mystructInfo.slot, 1), value)
        sstore(add(mystructInfo.slot, 2), myAddress)
        sstore(add(mystructInfo.slot, 3), email)
      }
      }
```

Comment: Check if this answer is enough for you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80529/how-to-get-access-to-the-storage-mapping-through-the-solidity-assembler. A few years back Howard wrote a series an articles about EVM and Solidity you could check those [Diving Into The Ethereum VM Part 3 — The Hidden Costs of Arrays](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-the-hidden-costs-of-arrays-28e119f04a9b).