# Call child contract functions from outside

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have ERC20 controller contract which deploys ERC20 contract.

```
contract ERC20Controller {
  ERC20 ercContract; 
  constructor {
    ercContract = new ERC20(); 
  }
}
```

Now I'm testing this contract in hardhat and want to call `balanceOf` function. I've expected that I can just call it this way: `controller.ercContract().balanceOf()` but it fails? 
Is the only option there to create function inside controller which calls balanceOf on child contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to define the `ercContract` variable as `public`. You can read this thread to learn more about visibility for storage variables: [Solidity: private vs public variables](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/solidity-private-vs-public-variables/25504#25504).

Second, you would have to create a custom function in the `ERC20Controller` contract if you want to call `ercContract.balanceOf`.

The `erc20Contract` variable is stored as an address in the `ERC20Controller` cotract. When you call `ercContract()` from outside the blockchain, you're not getting a contract instance back, but rather a simple address.